# How to implement google map SDK for iOS to iPhone 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I try to show custom map view using Google Maps SDK for iOS on iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 on simulator.

I create a UIViewController class for Google map
Here is code

//GoogleMapViewController.h

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>// for google map

@interface GoogleMapViewController : UIViewController{

    GMSMapView *mapView_;
}
```

//GoogleMapViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:13.909366 longitude:100.517446 zoom:5];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.view = mapView_;
}
```

and I load GoogleMapViewController to subview like this

//RealTimeMonitoring.h

```
@interface RealTimeMonitoring : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *googleMapView;
@end
```

//RealTimeMonitoring.m

```
#import "GoogleMapViewController.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

GoogleMapViewController *googleViwController = [[GoogleMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GoogleMapViewController" bundle:nil];
googleViwController.view.frame = self.googleMapView.bounds;
[self.googleMapView addSubview:googleViwController.view];
}
```

When I run it on iPhone 5 simulator it show correctly and the center of camera on map view look OK

[image: iPhone5 Result]

But when I run it on iPhone  simulator it seem to cut lower part a bit but the camera still center like it

[image: iPhone4 Result]

When I coding game using Coco2d I recall that I must set the size or init view according to the device. But when I use interface builder I don't know how.

**Question: How can I make it show like iPhone 5 on iPhone 4**

Ps. I still using macbook pro 13-inch Late 2011, Xcode 4.5.1 on OS X 10.7.5 and planing  to update to mavericks soon

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use storyboard with autolayout?

if so, go to the storyboard..select the view of the map and then go to

Editor > pin > top space to superview
Editor > pin > bottoms pace to superview
Editor > pin > leading space to superview
Editor > pin > trailing space to superview

Comment: Thank for quick answer.

I didn't use storyboard. Is there any other way or create storyboard will be easier?

Comment: I think at the storyboard as the best way to design UI for iOS...it takes just a little of time to learn how to use autolayout but then is wonderful...

Comment: Ok I will try to convert my project to use storyboard and try your approach.

Thank